# Show the equivalence $x=1$ $⟺$ $-ε<x-1<ε$ for all $ε>0$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show the equivalence $x=1 \Leftrightarrow-\epsilon\lt (x-1)\lt \epsilon$ for all $ε\gt0$.

So the first thing I thought to do was to prove both sides ($\Leftarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$) since this is an equivalence question.

i) To show $\Leftarrow$:

Suppose $x=1$, we have to show $-\epsilon \lt (x-1)\lt \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\gt0$.

$1<x+\epsilon $
If $x=1$ then $1\lt (1+\epsilon )$, $\epsilon \gt0$

$(x-1)\lt \epsilon$
$(x-\epsilon )\lt 1$

If $x=1$ then $1-ε<1$

Therefore $-\epsilon \lt 0$, so $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Then i would go on to prove the $\Rightarrow$side, but i'm not sure if i'm on the right line or not. Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x\neq1$. Then $x>1$ or $x<1$. Suppose that $x>1$. Now, let $\varepsilon= x-1$. Then $\varepsilon>0$, but it is *false* that $x-1<\varepsilon$ (they're equal).

The case in which $x<1$ is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you further explain why you let  ε=x−1?

Comment: So that $x-1=\varepsilon$, which is incompatible with the inequality $x-1<\varepsilon$. This is a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be :

$x = 1 \Leftrightarrow (x-1) = 0$ (Substract 1 on LHS and RHS)

Now, we know that -

$a = 0$ iff $\forall \epsilon \gt 0,  a\lt \epsilon$ (or, $\vert a \vert \lt \epsilon$) (Proof below - **C1**)

Using the above we have -

$-\epsilon \lt (x-1) \lt \epsilon$

Note that all implications are bi-directional so that the proof is immediately# complete.

---

#### Proof of C1-

Suppose to the contrary that $a \gt 0$. Then if we take $\epsilon := a/2$
, we have, $0\lt \epsilon \lt a$.

Therefore, it is false that $a \lt \epsilon \forall \epsilon \lt 0$ and we conclude that $a=0$.

The converse follows immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Assume $x>1.$ That is, $x=1+c$ with $c>0.$ Then, what happens if we consider $0<\epsilon<c?$